# Filemaker 12 set a script trigger on all layouts

Tags: triggers, filemaker

Is there a way to set a script trigger that across the entire database without having to set a trigger for all layouts individually?

The idea would be to show a dialog after inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, per FileMaker's Help page: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7465

> Layout script triggers can only be configured one layout at a time.

Depending on how you are trying to implement your solution, you might be able to use a Custom Menu (with FM Advanced) an On Timer script or a login script for a similar purpose.